# Updating contents of a file with gedit from ubuntu terminal

Tags: gedit

I have type "gedit filename.txt" on my command line in Ubuntu, but no Gedit window showed up. Instead my cursor keeps flashing, as if I could write things, but I have no way to type commands that work ... I tried pressing escape then ":wq" but nothing happened.
How can I go back to my command line normally, and how do I update files with gedit from the command line ?
Hope this is clear, please ask if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Gnome or are you in a shell? For console based editing, you should use vi or nano or some other console editor. 
Gedit will only work if you're using a window based graphical interface. (Gnome)
(also depending on the file, you might need to sudo to edit it)

Comment: I am using the shell (black window) I don't know how to get back to writing commands that work. Now, when I type enter i dont have the usual header with the username ...

Comment: Try pressing ctrl+c (abort command), it will break whatever process is running

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
gedit filename.txt &
```

For coming back to the command line use CTRL+z or CTRL+c.

For continuing you can must type "&" after any command that you type.

For viewing the active command, use this command:

```
jobs
```

For switching between jobs use this:

```
job %row mubber
```

For example: `job %1`